# No Xml response on live server - Cakephp

Tags: xml, cakephp

Hi i am developing a web application and I have build Rest Service which returns the response in xml. The strange this is that application is working perfectly fine over localhost and it returns the required xml. But on the live server whole application is working other than rest service i.e. whenever i call rest service in result browser shows nothing (while on chrome i get "No data from server" error). Can anyone tell me that what can be the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if your server allows the extension .xml for the correct MIME type. For a server with cPanel, you can find the advanced setting in MIME types and add this in:

MIME type: text/xml
Extensions: .xml xml

Different servers may have different settings.

Comment: There is another application on a server which is ROR application and it is generating perfect xml. Thanks for your help

Comment: Infact I have figured out the problem. The version of php on live server is 5.1.3 and i installed the same version on my system and now the same error is coming on my system. (Before I was using php 5.3 version and it was working fine with it). Poor me that i cannot change the php version on live server. :(